# Visualforce Button Not Appearing on Record After Spring 2020

Tags: spring-20

My org has two Visualforce buttons for technicians to clock in/out of work orders from the record detail page. While testing in a sandbox to ensure that we're not impacted by Spring 2020, we discovered that technicians with a certain profile were unable to see these buttons, while technicians with another profile were still able to. In production users with either profile can see the buttons. Switching the user's profile will allow them to see the buttons again.

The weird thing is that there's almost no difference between the profiles, at least not that I can see. Neither profile has access to any of the SObjects involved (it's all granted by permission set), neither has access to the Visualforce button's standard controller extension or any of the embedded lightning components' Apex controllers. All of this is granted by permission sets. The only difference I can tell is that the profile that has access has a bit more expansive reporting permissions. I tried granting these these to the profile that can't, but it didn't change anything.

I've confirmed that both users are seeing the same page layout, tried disabling critical updates, no results. We currently have a case open with Salesforce, but they're slow to respond and we're getting uncomfortably close to Spring 2020 going live. I know it's hard to help with an issue like this since it's some sort of set up issue, but can anyone think of any possible cause?

Comment: classic or lightning?

Comment: This is in Lightning.